# How to Load Balance or enhance DB performance at AWS RDS MySQL DB Instances

Tags: mysql, database, performance, amazon-web-services, optimization

Last night I asked a similar question at [DB StackExchange platform](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/179967/how-to-load-balance-aws-rds-database-instances-to-enhance-db-performance), but no one replied so putting my question here.

I have huge DB(almost 7-9GiB) over Amazon RDS also CPU Utilization & I/O is also high, I'm not good at optimizing Database queries, enhancing Data Performance and etc. I need help with this DB, in terms of optimization and improve server performance so that users can gain rich experience.

About my research:
As also mentioned there at DBA. Should I upgrade RDS t2.micro to premium db-instance? or create another DB replica on the premium server and balance this with help of EBS(Load Balancers). So, the server becomes smooth for at-least now. Likewise,
[RDS Load Balancing Tricks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiEWf.jpg)

Then, I need to optimize SQL queries and enhance APIs performance and update DataBase on RDS by removing EBS & Premium Server?

Comment: Please provide a few of the queries.  Include the SQL, `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  It may be something as simple as adding a composite index.

Answer (score 0):

Some general optimizations you could do,

- Instead of using t2.micro migrate to a instance class with high IO capacity (As you have mentioned). t2.micro is for general purpose and not recommend for production databses.
- Convert from standard storage to Provisioned IOPS storage (If you have high disk utilization, else a general purpose SSD would also be fine)
- Depending on the read traffic, you might want to consider using Read replicas.

Other than that, it will narrow down to [general DB optimization techniques](https://www.toptal.com/sql/sql-database-tuning-for-developers) such as proper indexing etc.

Some of the AWS RDS specific best practices are listed [in this doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_BestPractices.html).

Comment: @aaimaa-web-solutions I hope this answer helps you. If it does, I encourage you to upvote and accept it as it may help others.